# checking if sum of list is value in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a simple predicate that will determine if all the elements of a list add up to a sum, but I don't understand why mine isn't working.

It seems like it should work, but when i do list_sum([1,2,3],X) it returns no, or list_sum([1,2,3],6) it also returns null. Any ideas?

```
list_sum([],0).
list_sum([F], V) :- F=V.
list_sum([F|R], V) :- list_sum(R, V-F).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic must be explicitly evaluated. Try

```
list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([F|R], V) :- list_sum(R, S), V is S+F.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list_sum([],0).
list_sum([V], V).
list_sum([F,G|R], V) :- S is F + G, list_sum([S|R], V).
```